# Permanent SPF error: Void lookup limit of 2 exceeded

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, spf, godaddy, txt-record

I'm trying to fix my GoDaddy SPF settings.

I'm getting this error: "SPF record lookup and validation for: http://www.scoutbox.us|www.scoutbox.us

Permanent SPF error: Void lookup limit of 2 exceeded

SPF records are published in DNS as TXT records.

The TXT records found for your domain are:
Checking to see if there is a valid SPF record.

Results - Permanent Error Void lookup limit of 2 exceeded
No valid SPF record found of either type TXT or type SPF."

I just added a TXT record in my DNS (the recommended one for both outlook and workspace email from GoDaddy)

```
v=spf1 mx include:<http://secureserver.net|secureserver.net> -all
v=spf1 include:<http://spf.protection.outlook.com|spf.protection.outlook.com> -all
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Include should point to a domain that has a domain not a web page.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can have only one record, second after `include` has to be only a hostname. So:

```
v=spf1 mx include:secureserver.net include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```